# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, opencv

**the code is :**

```
import numpy
import cv2 as cv

cap=cv.VideoCapture(0)
while True :
    #ret will get non or value
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    #for make frames gray who did this library make RGB=>BGR
    gray=cv.cvtColor(frame,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow('fram',gray)
    #if the user click q or exit the vedio 
    if cv.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**the error is:
 error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNp3u.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv.VideoCapture(0)` instead of `cv.videoCapture(0)`. Your mistake is that you lower-cased the **V**, which should be upper-cased.
Source: [Opencv Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture)

Comment: the question was edited to be an entirely different issue.